# confusion on exercises from LEE's Book on Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading John Lee's  "***Riemannian Manifolds an Introduction to Curvature***" .
At page 15 exercise 2.3 asks to prove that there exist a smooth extension of a function defined on a embedded submanifold. The exercise is wrong for example we can take f(x)= 1/x defined on positive reals which is a embedded submanifold of $ 
\mathbb{R} $ . I think for a global extension we need the submanifold to be closed. Though this does not affect the later development because connection on a Riemannian manifold depends on the local behaviour of the vector fields. 
      Next at the page 157 I didn't get the definition of exterior angle which is to take the ***"oriented angle"*** on the closed interval [$ - \pi, \pi $ ]. Shouldn't be [ $ 0, \pi $].
And then determine the sign where they preserve the orientation or not. Otherwise there will be a ambiguity in the definition as there will be two possible choice of the angle in the given interval.
      Please do clarify . I am struck from further progression.

Answer (score 10):

You're right about exercise 2.3.  This is one of the corrections posted on my [webpage](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/riemannian.html); you should download that list and keep it nearby when you read.

As for the exterior angle, I really did mean $[-\pi,\pi]$.  If the vertex is concave, the rotation from $\dot\gamma(a_i^-)$ to $\dot\gamma(a_i^+)$ will be counterclockwise.